# calling calculating functions in Python

Tags: python, function

it asks for sales tax, but then prints a long number for total tax

```
#This program will ask user for sales and calcutate state, county, and total sales tax.

#This module calculates the county tax

def askTotalSales():
    totalSales=float(input("Enter sales for the month: "))
    print()
    return totalSales
def countyTax(totalSales):
    countyTax= .02
    
    return totalSales*countyTax
    
def stateTax(totalSales):
    stateTax= .04
    return totalSales *stateTax


#This module calculates the state tax


#this module will calculate total sales tax
def calcTotalTax(stateTax, countyTax):
    totalTax=stateTax+countyTax
    print()
    return totalTax

#printData
def printTotalTax (countyTax, stateTax, totalTax):
    print ('County sales tax is'+countyTax)
    print('State sales tax is' +stateTax)
    print('Total sales tax is' +totalTax)

def main():
    totalSales=askTotalSales()
    countySales=countyTax(totalSales)
    stateSales=stateTax(totalSales)
    totalTax=float(input(calcTotalTax))
    
    



main()
```

an online class with zero instruction is not ideal, i've pored throjugh these pages and some youtube videos to come up with this

i understand the issue may be with my Cacltotal tax function- i'm unsure of how to call it

Comment: _but then prints a long number for total tax_ Show us that output, and explain what you wanted instead.

Comment: You just need `totalTax=calcTotalTax(stateTax, countyTax)`

Comment: Careful about using variable names that are the same as the function names...

Comment: Why are you taking an online class with zero instruction?  There are a lot of really excellent free tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
totalTax = float(input(calcTotalTax))
```

`calcTotalTax` is a function, not a number. The program will print the function address (which should seem like a random large number) rather than an output. This should be,

```
totalTax = float(calcTotalTax(stateSales, countrySales))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/newish/Documents/progproj6.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/newish/Documents/progproj6.py", line 41, in main
    totalTax=float(calcTotalTax(stateTax, countyTax))
  File "/Users/newish/Documents/progproj6.py", line 26, in calcTotalTax
    totalTax=calcTotalTax(stateTax+ countyTax)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'

 thank you, my new error is this.

Answer (score 0):

Pay careful attention to which arguments each function takes (it's specified when you `def` the function), and make sure you're passing those arguments when you call the function.  Also, be careful not to give variables the same names as your functions; each name can only refer to one thing at a time.

In real life you usually don't want `print` calls in all of your functions, but since you had them in your original code I added strings to them that let you see which function is being called when:

```
def ask_total_sales():
    return float(input("Enter sales for the month: "))

def calc_county_tax(total_sales):
    print("Calculating county tax...")
    return total_sales * 0.02
    
def calc_state_tax(total_sales):
    print("Calculating state tax...")
    return total_sales * 0.04

def calc_total_tax(county_tax, state_tax):
    print("Calculating total tax...")
    return county_tax + state_tax

def print_total_tax(county_tax, state_tax, total_tax):
    print ('County sales tax is', county_tax)
    print('State sales tax is', state_tax)
    print('Total sales tax is', total_tax)

def main():
    total_sales = ask_total_sales()
    county_tax = calc_county_tax(total_sales)
    state_tax = calc_state_tax(total_sales)
    total_tax = calc_total_tax(county_tax, state_tax)
    print_total_tax(county_tax, state_tax, total_tax)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that (for example) in the `main` function above, we call the function `calc_total_tax` with the arguments `county_tax` and `state_tax`, and what it returns gets assigned to the value `total_tax`, which we then pass to `print_total_tax` along with `county_tax` and `state_tax` (which we got by calling `calc_county_tax` and `calc_state_tax`).

```
Enter sales for the month: 500
Calculating county tax...
Calculating state tax...
Calculating total tax...
County sales tax is 10.0
State sales tax is 20.0
Total sales tax is 30.0
```

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':    please tell me why this is necessary. also, can we be friends?!!

Comment: The `if __name__ == '__main__'` makes it so that your `main()` function is only called if this file is the "main" script when you call it.  It doesn't really matter when you're starting out and only have one file, but later as you have multiple files/modules it becomes important to separate what happens in each file at import time vs what happens when you run it as a standalone script.